# Chrome doesn't recognize the language of the site

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate, lang

We're trying to enable Chrome's translation prompt in [El Espectador](https://www.elespectador.com) site.

Here's how the prompt appears in the address bar in sites like [El Pais](https://elpais.com/america/) but not in our's.

[image: Translation prompt in El Pais]

We've tried setting the language of the site in several ways:

- HTML tag: `<html lang="es">`
- META tag: `<meta name="language" content="spanish"/>`
- content-language header: [image: site's header]

Are we missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [El Espectador](https://www.elespectador.com) have the following tag:

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate">
```

Remove it and it should work.